# spring-mvc multipart file upload

Tags: spring-mvc, file-upload

I have a jsp page where in I upload an image(MultipartFile) and store the image name in database and the image file in a central repo.
Now when I want to edit the image (when the page loads) the image gets displayed as the src is the actual path from repo. However now if I just save it the fileName is empty.
Is there any way that I can get the fileName

Comment: Please, provide your code

Comment: `<form:form action="save" method="POST" commandName="banner"
<div>
<table>
<tr>
<td>
<div>
<c:if test="${empty banner.imageWeb}">
<img id="img-upload-web"
src="${ctx}/assets/images/cms/no_preview.png">
</c:if>
<c:if test="${not empty banner.imageWeb}">
<img class="thumbnail img-preview col-lg-12"
id="img-upload-web"
src="/imageDir/${banner.imageWeb.originalFilename}">
</c:if>
</div>
<div>
<label> UPLOAD<form:input
type="file" id="imgInp1"
name="imageWeb" path="imageWeb" value="${imageWeb}" />
</label>
</div>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
</form:form>`

Comment: `public class Banner implements Serializable { // serial version id private MultipartFile imageWeb; // GETTERS and Setters goes here }`